# Ring and Pole - Box2d

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-iphone, physics

How I can make a b2Body in box2d so that it could form a ring which does not collide from the center just like a ring. like when we flick the object and there's another body (like pole), the pole can go inside from the ring.

like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to view the scene from the side? Pretty easy to be done. Just create two circles that are connected to each others with some space in between:

```
O    O
```

You just draw the actual ring (the part not colliding) over the "empty" space.